# Full GROUP BY in MySQL 5.7 breaks de-dupe queries

Tags: mysql

Prior to MySQL 5.7, I was able to dedupe queries by using GROUP BY as long as the query results were done in such a way that the duplicates had the same data and were already in the sort order I wanted.

I got really good at that.

Now, with 5.7 and only_full_group_by mode, those queries are invalid. I've already been through the 5 stages of grief over it, and am working to update / improve my queries to be more standard.

the problem is: when I do a LEFT JOIN (in some cases) it produces rows and rows of (essentially) duplicate information. I get that they are not technically duplicates because some column may be different. And, I see a lot of questions about this in a general way. One such use case is "find the highest value for X in the day." You used to just use ORDER BY x DESC with a GROUP BY  and *poof* you had it. Now, you have to do LEFT JOINs and look for NULLs. (Part of me still wonders "why is this better?" but that's off topic).

....but I want to know what best practice replaced using GROUP BY to remove these duplicates? SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Good idea. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can yourself other than deleting this and opening another.  A mod will likely be by before too long and migrate it for you though, especially since you said good idea. ; )

Comment: Show us an actual example and you'll get an answer. The "poof you get it" that you used may sometimes produce wrong, inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT` dedups on all columns. Sounds like that is what you want. `GROUP BY` has other purposes.

But I smell another problem here...  A common pattern is

```
SELECT
    ... some columns, some aggregates
    FROM a
    JOIN b  ON ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY some columns
```

This is rather inefficient (even when you don't run into the "only group by" restriction).  First the `JOIN` is done.  This inflates the number of rows, and builds a big tmp table.  Then the `GROUP BY` is used to deflate it, often back to exactly the number of rows that are in one of the tables.

There are a couple of workarounds.  But the depend on the details of the query (please show us the query).

If all the aggregates are on columns in, say, `b`, then use a derived table to first compute all the aggregates from `b`, then join the result of that to `a` to get the rest of the columns.

If there is only one aggregate, and even if the `JOIN` is actually `LEFT JOIN`, then

```
SELECT some columns,
       ( SELECT ... FROM b WHERE ... GROUP BY ...) -- correlated subquery
    FROM a
    -- no GROUP BY needed here, so no inflate-deflate inefficiency
```